# Best way to join different tables in MySQL based on condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

`Licenses`:

```
 License    |    object_type_id  |  selected_object_type_id  
  L1                   1                     300 
  L4                   2                     300
  L5                   3                     127 
  ..                   ..                    ...
```

`object_type`

```
id    |    type  |
1          Main
2          Sub
3          Feature
```

`Main`

```
id   | product  | ....
1        PMA
2        PMB
3        PMC
...       ...
300       PMZZ
```

`Sub`

```
id  | product | ...
1       PSA1
2       PSA2
3       ...
300     PSAZZ
```

`Feature`

```
id  |  Feature|  ...
1        FO1
2        FO2
3        FO3
..        ..
127       FFZ127
```

I want to have a final table called "license_mapping"

`license_mapping`

```
 license   |   license_object | license_object_type
   L1              PMZZ              Main
   L4              PSAZZ             Sub
   L5              FFZ127            Feature
```

The logic goes that for a given license, find the `licenses.object_type_id`. Depending on value of `object_type.type` where `licenses.object_type_id = object_type.id`  choose the product or feature from the corresponding table that matches the `licenses.selected_object_type_id`.

But how do I handle the case `Main` and `Sub` since they have the same id and also the same column name?

If I am to write pseudo SQL statement it would be the following, the last line is where I don't understand how to do it correctly.

```
 SELECT
   L.License,
   CASE WHEN OT.type = 'Main' THEN M.Product WHEN OT.type = 'Sub' THEN S.Product WHEN OT.Type = 'Feature' THEN F.Feature END AS License_Objects,
   OT.type As license_object_type
 FROM 
   Licenses L
   JOIN object_type OT on L.object_type_id = OT.id
   JOIN Feature F on L.object_type_id = F.id
   JOIN Main M when OT.type = 'Main' and Sub S when OT.type = 'Sub'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `LEFT JOIN` to each of the `Main`, `Sub` and `Feature` tables on the `selected_object_type_id` value and select the appropriate value from those tables based on the `object_type`:

```
SELECT l.License, 
       CASE WHEN ot.type = 'Main' THEN m.product 
            WHEN ot.type = 'Sub' THEN s.product
            WHEN ot.type = 'Feature' THEN f.Feature
       END AS license_object,
       ot.type AS license_object_type
FROM licenses l
JOIN object_type ot ON ot.id = l.object_type_id
LEFT JOIN main m ON m.id = l.selected_object_type_id
LEFT JOIN sub s ON s.id = l.selected_object_type_id
LEFT JOIN feature f ON f.id = l.selected_object_type_id
ORDER BY l.License
```

Output for your sample data:

```
License     license_object  license_object_type
L1          PMZZ            Main
L4          PSAZZ           Sub
L5          FFZ127          Feature
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dSuWsuhXMacuRzRk8rJ1JN/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `JOIN`s to `Main`.  However, presumably there is also a condition on the `id` -- and it is not clear what that should be `JOIN`ed to:

```
 SELECT L.License,
        (CASE WHEN OT.type = 'Main' THEN MS.Product
              WHEN OT.type = 'Sub' THEN MS.Product
              WHEN OT.Type = 'Feature' THEN F.Feature
         END) AS License_Objects,
        OT.type As license_object_type
FROM Licenses L JOIN
     object_type OT
     ON L.object_type_id = OT.id JOIN
     Feature F 
     ON L.object_type_id = F.id LEFT JOIN
     Main MM
     ON MM.ID = ??? AND OT.type = 'Main' LEFT JOIN
     MAIN MS 
     ON MS.ID = ??? AND OT.type = 'Sub';
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I do not understand what you mean by "condition on the "id" and it is not clear" which part is not clear?

Comment: The ID in Main and Sub table should be the ID in the selected_object_type_id column

Comment: @kspr . . . Just plug in the column it should refer to and see if the answer does what you need.